# Why is this line from a file not the same as the string with the same characters?

Tags: java, file-io

I keep trying to check to see if two lines have the same content so I can keep it out of the file when it's all said and done. However, the if statement that checks to see if the two are similar isn't working properly. Even though the lines are seemingly similar, the if statement still sees it as false.

```
String fileLine = "";
String comp = "";
BufferedReader tempRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("res/save.sav")));
PrintWriter tempWrite = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("res/tempSave.sav")));
for(String s: addToSave){
    while((fileLine = tempRead.readLine()) != null){
        comp = s.substring(0, s.length()-4);
        System.out.print(fileLine.substring(0, comp.length()-1));
        System.out.print(comp);
        if(fileLine.substring(0, comp.length()-2).equals(comp)){
            System.out.println("is gud");
        }
    }
}
tempWrite.close();
tempRead.close();
```

Comment: Well, bear in mind that when you're talking about computers, "seemingly similar" is definitely "not the same."

Comment: In one statement you have `fileLine.substring(0, comp.length()-1)`, in another you have `fileLine.substring(0, comp.length()-2)`. Which is It supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You will never have a string of one length, `comp.length() - 2`, be equal to another string of a different length, `comp.length()`.